# Jquery, Time Input

Tags: jquery, time

I want to force a time format, for example when somebody writes '22222' they will get '22:22'.

For now, I have done something like this:

```
    $("#{{id}}_timecompleter").keyup(function(){
        var value = $("#{{id}}_timecompleter").val();
            if (value.length == 2){
                $("#{{id}}_timecompleter").val( value+":" )
            }
    });
```

It works fine but, for example, when somebody will hold '2' and type '22222' it won't work. The same it is possible to write "22", my script will add ":" and convert it to "22:" but the user can go back and add a number before : and he would get for example "222:".
The same when I have "22:" and i will delete "2" i will get "2::".

Maybe somebody has got a better idea of a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found solution. I have install Jquery plugin -> MeioMask. It works fine. Link to it:
https://github.com/fabiomcosta/jquery-meiomask

Answer (score 1):

Instead of on `.keyup`, maybe you could use `.blur`. So, when user is done typing his value, his value would ALWAYS change to format hh:mm

Comment: It will change my format only when somebody will click on document or press for example tab. But It won't change this format immediately :/ And for example when somebody would types only 4 numbers i would have to check this format.

Comment: The benefit with using .blur is that you can truncate the excess values greater than 4 characters!

Comment: Yep, maybe you're right but I Found better solution -> MeioMask Plugin.